# How to delete a single cached username from Chrome on mobile devices?

Tags: chrome-for-android

I'm using Chrome 109.0.5414.117 on Android 11. In the Chrome for Windows desktop version, I understand that you can delete a single cached username by highlighting the item and pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.

However, does anyone know if this is possible in Chrome mobile?

Comment: By "single cached username", did you mean the autofill suggestion on the text input?

Comment: Yes, that right. It's the autofill suggestion when I put the cursor  on the textbox.